# Map entity structure to map of maps using streams

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors

I have the entities:

```
public class Library {
  String name;
  Set<Book> books;
}

public class Book {
  String isbn;
  String title;
}
```

Now I need a

```
Map<String, Map<String, Book>> mapByLibraryNameAndIsbn;
```

where the key of the first `Map` is the name of the `Library` and the key of the second `Map` the isbn of the `Book`.

To do that, I want to use java streams and some collectors. I tried it with groupingBy and toMap, but with any success.

**Update 1:**

I tried so far

```
Map<String, List<Book>> libraryList.stream().collect(groupingBy(l -> l.getName(), toList()));
```

but I just got a `Map` of `List`s.

Any ideas? TIA!

Comment: What do you start off with? A single `Library` instance? A `List<Library>`?

Comment: @Mureinik With a `List<Library>`

Comment: What code have you written so far and where are you stuck?

Comment: @Michael: I just added an update to my question with a code example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you start with a `List<Library>`, you probably want to combine `Collectors.toMap()` with 2 mapping functions:

1. A Library -> String mapper for the keys (returns `name`)
2. A Library -> Map mapper for the values.

For the second mapper you probably want to stream the `Set` of books, collect them into a `Map` similar to the 'outer' map using, again, 2 (different) mapping functions:

1. A Book -> String mapper for the keys (returns `isbn`)
2. An identity mapper for the value (returns the book itself).

So something like:

```
List<Library> libs;
// populate the libraries
Map<String,Map<String,Book>> map = libs.
    stream().
    collect(Collectors.toMap(l -> l.name, l -> {
        return l.books.
            stream().
            collect(Collectors.toMap(b -> b.isbn, Function.identity()));  
    }));
```

List libs;

Comment: Thanks! That's it!

Answer (score 2):

Using method references and static import:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toMap;

Map<String, Map<String, Book>> map = libs.stream().collect(
        toMap(Library::getName, 
                l -> l.getBooks().stream().collect(
                        toMap(Book::getIsbn, b -> b))));
```